# How to test whether an uploaded Excel file meets requirements

Tags: r, shiny

**Background**

Suppose I have a `shiny` app where the user can upload an Excel file. The users will have access to a certain Excel template and I want to make sure that only copies of this template are uploaded.

**My current approach**

My current approach is now as follows:

1. Check if sheet name *xyz* is present -> if not throw an error
2. Read data from sheet *xyz*, compare column names with requirements -> if missing columns throw an error
3. Repeat for all necessary sheets

**Problem with the current approach**

This requires a lot of hard coding required sheet names and required column names and becomes tedious.

**Question**

So my question: how can I assure that the user provides a valid file? What strategies do you usually use to make sure that the uploaded file can be properly processed by your apps?

---

**Pseudo Code**

```
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)
ui <- fluidPage(fileInput("file", "Upload Excel"))
server <- function(input, output, session) {
    observe({
      req(input$file)
      sheet1 <- tryCatch(read_xlsx(input$file$datapath, sheet = "xyz"),
          error = function(e) {
             ## do some sort of error handling, e.g. write to a reactiveValue list
          })
      if (!all(.REQUIRED_FIELDS_FOR_XYZ %in% names(sheet1))) {
          ## signal error
      }
    })
}
```

Comment: Couldn't you use your template directly as a test? Like `identical(names(template), names(upload_xlsx))`, same with sheets etc?

Comment: Yeah, this would indeed be helpful. But I must admit that I am bit lost of which library to use for that. Cause with `readxl::read_xlsx` I have to provide a sheet name for example. In your proposal: what would `str(template)` print out?

Comment: I use `xlsx` package. Here I can read an excel file by providing the index. `xlsx::read.xlsx('test.xlsx', 1)` This returns a `data.frame`, so `str` would print dimensions and column names and data structure.

Comment: Actually, you put me on the right track. I think I will upload the template file and derive sheet names column names etc from there as a mockup. If you bother to formulate an answer I will happily accept as you put me on the right track. +1

Answer (score 1):

If you are already using Excel, why not use a Macro to do the work for you.  Consider listing file paths, checking format types, cell addresses, cell values, etc.  The Macro below will do most of the heavy lifting for you.

```
Sub GetFolder_Data_Collection()

    Dim colFiles As Collection, c As Range
    Dim strPath As String, f, sht As Worksheet
    Dim wbSrc As Workbook, wsSrc As Worksheet
    Dim rw As Range
    Dim sh As Worksheet, flg As Boolean

    Set sht = ActiveSheet

    strPath = ThisWorkbook.Path

    Set colFiles = GetFileMatches(strPath, "*.xlsx", True)

    With sht
        .Range("A:I").ClearContents
        .Range("A1").Resize(1, 5).Value = Array("Name", "Path", "Cell", "Value", "Numberformat")
        Set rw = .Rows(2)
    End With

    For Each f In colFiles
        Set wbSrc = Workbooks.Open(f)
        Set wsSrc = wbSrc.Sheets(1)
        For Each c In wsSrc.Range(wsSrc.Range("A1"), _
                                  wsSrc.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft)).Cells


            rw.Cells(2).Value = wbSrc.Path
            sht.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=rw.Cells(1), Address:=wbSrc.Path, TextToDisplay:=wbSrc.Name
            rw.Cells(3).Value = c.Address(False, False)
            rw.Cells(4).Value = c.Value
            rw.Cells(5).Value = c.NumberFormat

            i = 6
            For Each sh In Worksheets
                If sh.Name Like "Sheet1*" Or sh.Name Like "*Sheet2*" Then rw.Cells(i).Value = sh.Name & " Exists"
                i = i + 1
            Next


            Set rw = rw.Offset(1, 0)
        Next c
        wbSrc.Close False
    Next f
End Sub


'Return a collection of file objects given a starting folder and a file pattern
'  e.g. "*.txt"
'Pass False for last parameter if don't want to check subfolders
Function GetFileMatches(startFolder As String, filePattern As String, _
                    Optional subFolders As Boolean = True) As Collection

    Dim fso, fldr, f, subFldr
    Dim colFiles As New Collection
    Dim colSub As New Collection

    Set fso = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject")
    colSub.Add startFolder

    Do While colSub.Count > 0
        Set fldr = fso.GetFolder(colSub(1))
        colSub.Remove 1

        For Each f In fldr.Files
            If UCase(f.Name) Like UCase(filePattern) Then colFiles.Add f
        Next f
        If subFolders Then
            For Each subFldr In fldr.subFolders
                colSub.Add subFldr.Path
            Next subFldr
        End If
    Loop
    Set GetFileMatches = colFiles
End Function
```

PUT THIS CODE IN AN XLSB OR XLSM EXCEL FILE IN THE SAME FOLDER AS YOUR EXCEL FILES.

It's probably just easier to do this kind of thing with Excel, and I'm a huge proponent of using the right tool for the job.

Comment: +1 for "using the right tool for the job". However, I do not see how this would help me here. Because with the Excel approach I make sure that the template is filled correctly. But I want to assure that the user uploads indeed an instance of this template and not any arbitrary Excel file. And this I think I have to check on the `shiny` side of the problem. Am I overlooking something?

Comment: I made some changes to the code.  Try this version and feed back.  I don't know if this is exactly what you want, but it should get you started in the right direction.